# Add dynamically new input fields from multiselect choosen list

Tags: javascript, html

I have this modal form and i want to insert new fields when someone select more than on item in the second select, so, if I choose 3 itens, 3 new input fields are added dynamically  to the form.

This is my form

```
 <!--Nova visita-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModalNovaVisita" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header card-infos">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Registar Nova Visita de Estudo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="novaVisita" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Escola:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="idEscola" name="idEscola" required>
                            <option value="0">Escolha a escola desta visita</option>
                            <option value="1">Carmo</option>
                            <option value="2">Frei</option>
                            <option value="3">Santa Maria Maior</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">Turmas participantes na visita(tecla "shift" para seguidos, "ctrl"
                            para
                            separados)</label>
                        <select name="turmasVisitas[]" id="turmasVisitas" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="height: 100pt;" onchange="getCount();">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Destino:</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="localVisita">
                            <input class="form-control" name="novoDestino" id="novoDestino" placeholder="Destino desta visita">
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="data">Data da partida:</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="startDatePicker">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="data">Hora da partida:</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="horaPartida">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="part" onchange="validateHhMm(this)" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="ajaxDivErroHora"  style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="data">Data do regresso:</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="endDatePicker">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="data">Hora do regresso:</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="horaChegada">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cheg" onchange="validateHhMm(this)"  />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="ajaxDivErroHora1"  style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Professores Acompanhantes:</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="acompanhantes">
                            <input class="form-control" name="acomp" id="acomp" placeholder="">
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Departamento(s):</label>
                        <select name="dpt[]" id="dpt" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="height: 100pt;">
                            <?php echo $optionDpt ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Áreas/Disciplinas Envolvidas:</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="areas_disc">
                            <input class="form-control" name="areas" id="areas" placeholder="">
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="iti">Itinerário:</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="itiVisita">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="iti" name="iti"></textarea>
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Domínios (tecla "shift" para seguidos, "ctrl" para
                            separados):</label>
                        <select name="dominios[]" id="dominios" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="height: 100pt;">
                            <?php echo $optionDominios ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="iti">Plano de Ocupação(turmas não abrangidas pela vista):</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="itiVisita">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="planoRecuperacao" name="planoRecuperacao"></textarea>
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                        <legend class="scheduler-border card-infos">Transporte</legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="notas">Tipo: </label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="optradio"
                                                   value="Autocarro Autarquia">Autocarro Autarquia
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="optradio" value="Autocarro Alugado">Autocarro
                                            Alugado
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="optradio" value="Outros">Outros
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="custo">Total Alunos:</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="totalVisita">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alunos"
                                                   placeholder="ex: 100"/>
                                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"
                                                                                      aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="custo">Custo Individual:</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="custoVisita">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="custo"
                                                   placeholder="ex: 20 €"/>
                                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-eur"
                                                                                      aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 control-label">Observações:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="obs" id="obs"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="userid" id="userid"
                               value="<?php echo $id_prof; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="novaVisita" id="novaVisita" value="novaVisita">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my javascript is this :

```
function getCount() {
    var count = $("#turmasVisitas :selected").length;
    console.log(count);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        $('<input type="text"/>').appendTo('novaVisita');
    }
}
```

Nothing appears with this code...

Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right! You've two small bugs in there :

1. You should addd the id sign `#` to this line :

   ```
   $('<input type="text"/>').appendTo('#novaVisita');
   ____________________________________^
   ```
2. Remove the `length` from the loop since count is already a number :

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
   _____________________^^^^^^^
   ```

   Should be :

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   ```

Hope this helps.

```js
function getCount() {
  var count = $("#turmasVisitas :selected").length;
  console.log(count);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      $('<input type="text"/>').appendTo('#novaVisita');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Nova visita-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModalNovaVisita" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
   aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header card-infos">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Registar Nova Visita de Estudo</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="novaVisita" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Escola:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="idEscola" name="idEscola" required>
                          <option value="0">Escolha a escola desta visita</option>
                          <option value="1">Carmo</option>
                          <option value="2">Frei</option>
                          <option value="3">Santa Maria Maior</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <select name="turmasVisitas[]" id="turmasVisitas" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="height: 100pt;" onchange="getCount();">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
             </form>
             <br><br><br>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, now it works but it gives me several inputs...if i choose 2, it gives 6 input fields

Comment: Have you checked the snippet in my answer ? it gives you the right number of inputs.

Comment: But you didn't remove the old inputs when you make a new select

Answer (score 0):

`.appendTo('#novaVisita')`, you forgot the `#`

Otherwise it should work.

Comment: What does the `console.log(count)` output?

Comment: the console.log(count) gives me the total itens selected, but the loop doesn't seems to be working, i put a console log inside and no values are given

Comment: @Zakaria is right, it should be `i < count`, not `i < count.length`.